# Cannot find module 'fs-extra' error when launching tests despite the module is present in cypress

Tags: cypress, fs-extra

Just encountered the issue. After launching my tests this error appears in the cypress context window.

```
 Can't start server

The plugins file is missing or invalid.

Your pluginsFile is set to /Users/alexanderti/WebstormProjects/klickly-autotests-js/cypress/plugins/index.js, but either the file is missing, it contains a syntax error, or threw an error when required. The pluginsFile must be a .js or .coffee file.

Please fix this, or set pluginsFile to false if a plugins file is not necessary for your project.

Error: Cannot find module 'fs-extra'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:473:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexanderti/WebstormProjects/klickly-autotests-js/cypress/plugins/index.js:51:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexanderti/WebstormProjects/klickly-autotests-js/cypress/plugins/index.js:165:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:642:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:653:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at module.exports (/Users/alexanderti/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.4.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_plugins.js:118:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexanderti/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.4.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/child/index.js:9:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexanderti/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.4.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/child/index.js:11:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:642:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:653:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:683:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:196:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:622:3
```

Everything worked fine until I accidentally installed fs-exta module in package.json via UI prompt in Webstorm and then uninstalled it. Also removed ./node_modules and installed back.
But the error remains.

I've checked modules availability via npm ls fs-extra and it shows that it present

```
─┬ cypress@3.4.0
│ └── fs-extra@5.0.0 
├─┬ mochawesome-merge@2.1.0
│ └── fs-extra@7.0.1 
└─┬ mochawesome-report-generator@4.1.0
  └── fs-extra@7.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by re-installing node_modules directory but with package-lock.json deleted, perhaps because of this it was looking on old version. Now fixed

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your package.json:

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
```

solved the problem for me. I also added two more to avoid more problems:

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

is that sort of solution ?
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/21615#issuecomment-1170103810

- step 1

delete the caches

- step 2

reinstall cypress

- and  I got the old version successfully